# facebooktoolkit and C# photo upload problem

Tags: c#, facebook, upload, photo

I need help with integrating facebook into my desktop application. It's developed with C# - target framework is .NET framework 4.0.
I'm using http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

The problem is that I can't get the users albums although my app has permission for it, and for all to be more confusing I can get statuses, comments, friends, etc.
I have this in designer:

```
this.fbMyApp = new Facebook.Winforms.Components.FacebookService(this.components);
this.fbMyApp.ApplicationKey = "myappkey_goes_here";
this.fbMyApp.SessionKey = null;
this.fbMyApp.uid = ((long)(0));
```

And I've used this code(I've set all permissions for testing purposes):

```
fbMyApp.ConnectToFacebook(new List<Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions>() { 
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.create_event,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.create_note,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.email,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.offline_access,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.photo_upload,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.read_mailbox,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.read_stream,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.rsvp_event,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.share_item,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.sms,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.status_update,
            Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.video_upload
        });
```

Now if I do this(after user has logged in):

```
MessageBox.Show("TOTAL statuses: " + fbMyApp.Status.Get().Count.ToString());
```

I will get the number of user statuses, and could read them. However if I do this:

```
MessageBox.Show("TOTAL albums: " + fbMyApp.Photos.GetAlbums().Count.ToString());
```

I get zero, although user has about 10 albums. I need this, cause this way I can access the album IDs and could be able to upload a photo to specific album. Any idea why this isn't working or does anybody have any better suggestion for some facebook toolkit for C#?

Comment: Ok, I'm not an expert, but is it all the permissions? There's no permission for reading photos/albums of the user. Just in case you may have forgotten that permission, if there is.

Comment: Nope, that's all permissions I could add(that facebook toolkit has defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request "user_photos" [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) from Facebook. I haven't used this toolkit as I prefer to make simple graph rest calls dynamically instead of having a huge library.  I imagine you could download the source and recompile it, adding the missing permission.  You could also switch to this [library](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) which is alot more up to date with current Facebook functionality.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the actual permission I needed. I've changed the source code of the toolkit(enums), recompiled it and it works! I will see if I will switch to that library cause this one does the job.
Million times thanks! ;)